# I can make my scatterplot, but I can not draw my line with matplotlib in the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, regression, scatter-plot

I am a beginner so this might be a stupid question. If I run the following code, I get shown the scatterplot of `x` and `y`, but the regression line `plt.plot(x, estimated_y, color="r", linewidth=3.0)` does not show up. I estimated `y` using the covariance matrix. `x`, `y` and `estimated_y` are all numpy arrays. If I run `plt.plot(x, estimated_y, color="r", linewidth=3.0)` alone, I get shown an empty figure.

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, estimated_y, color="r", linewidth=3.0) 
plt.show()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Difficult to say what you did, if you do not show the entire code and data set. For a start: Are you sure `estimated_y` contains data and is within the limits of the figure?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks quite fine. I added some random data to create a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy data
x = list(range(0,10))
y = list(range(10,0,-1))
estimated_y = [1]*10

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, estimated_y, color="r", linewidth=3.0) 
plt.show()
# do not add anything to the axes after this command. The command forces to terminate the "rendering", which is why everything afterwards opens a new plot
```

The output looks good:
[image: dummy data image]

However, you can make sure that you plot to the same axes (a figure may hold several axes or "subplots") by

```py
# open a figure + create a single axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.plot(x, estimated_y, color="r", linewidth=3.0) 
plt.show()
```

Any plotting function that you call from the base, e.g. `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` or `plt.plot()` since you ave renamed/imported part of the library as `plt`, will plot to the axis that is currently active. This should work in your case.

The good thing, when working with axes is, you can count the number of lines that were plotted on them:
`len(ax.get_lines())`

> `1`

It is one, because `scatter()` does not plot "lines" but "points"... Now, if you call it with your data, it should also return `1`. If it does and you can't see the red line, it might be that your data contains `NaN`s or that it was plotted out of limits. It if returns `0`, you have plotted it to some different (perhaps invisible or not-yet-drawn) axis.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It still doesnt work strangely. Actually, i've tried to use your variation with the subplot and now it tells me there are 20 lines plotted if i ask for len(ax.get_lines()).  Probably the reason for that: my numpy array estimated_y contains 20 numbers.

Comment: hm, I doubt this. You could check this hypothesis though, by calling `ax.plot(x, estimated_y.tolist()) `